# How to create tables in Basket ? or any other similar softwares?

Tags: notes

I was searching for notebook softwares. Installed zim, cherrytree & basket
Basket is best of them, But unable to create tables. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Basket has the tablet function hability, but you can make a table on LifreOffice and paste it there.

Comment: yes, I did that, But it shows the whole content in black ( black background, Light grey font )

Comment: I tried in mine and it pastes the table ok, it just doesn't show the borders.

Comment: Okay, I'll try again, Look for some settings like changing background colour.  Thank you